# node: how to extend module.paths

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I need to have access via require to my custom static files.
Therefor I created a directory 'assets' and promoted it to package:

```
|-assets
|    |-default-asset.json
|    |-package.json
```

where package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "assets",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./default-asset.json"
}
```

I needed to set the "main" property to something existing within the packe to not become ignored by node. How ever, now the package is part of the node_modules library root.

But when I call node to check module.paths its still not listed:

```
(base) ➜  server git:(master) ✗ node
Welcome to Node.js v12.13.1.
Type ".help" for more information.
> module.paths
[
  '/.../server/repl/node_modules',
  '/.../server/node_modules',
  '/.../node_modules',
  '/user/node_modules',
  '/home/node_modules',
  '/node_modules',
  '/home/user/.node_modules',
  '/home/user/.node_libraries',
  '/usr/lib/node'
]
>
```

That's probably a problem, because when trying to require one of the files from within the folder I still have got the exception:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './assets/default-asset.json'
Require stack:
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES, i finally managed to fix it, and for any other persons who struggles with it here is how:

1. The custom package need to be referenced from the app/package.json and
2. even more importantly, from package-lock.json with `"version": "file:custom-assets"` annotation!
3. The package.json must contain a "main" entry which references one of the files inside and its path must start with `./`!!!
4. The usage of the asset must NOT start with `./` but `/`!!!

Now the path is there:

```
$ node 
> module.paths
[
  '.../important-code-snippets/JavaScript/require-custom-assets/repl/node_modules',
  '.../important-code-snippets/JavaScript/require-custom-assets/node_modules',
```

Here is also a full running example: https://github.com/Macilias/important-code-snippets/tree/master/JavaScript/require-custom-assets